# How to get connection strings / endpoints of my xDB Cloud Set

Tags: xdb, cloud

Sitecore has provisioned xDB Cloud Set for me. How can I get connection strings and/or endpoints of my xDB Cloud Set?

For example, I want to connect to databases in MongoDB using [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get connection strings and/or endpoints of xDB Cloud Set that is based on Sitecore xDB Cloud services `v1.0` or `v2.0`, you have to perform the following steps:

1. Get the *Sitecore Nexus Auth* key to talk to xDB Cloud services.
2. Get the *Deployment ID* of xDB Set you are interested in.
3. Get a list of endpoints for the specified xDB Set.

#### Sitecore Nexus Auth Key

To get the key, call the [SSO Encode Sitecore License](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/81/xdb_cloud/customizing/rest_api_reference_for_the_xdb_cloud_service#_SSO_Encode_Sitecore) REST API:

#### Request

```
POST https://gateway-sso-scs.cloud.sitecore.net/api/License/Encode
Content-Type: application/xml
```

#### Request Headers

The `Content-Type` is used to declare the general type of data. Set this header to **application/xml**.

#### Request Body

The body of the request contains sitecore license file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.sitecore.net/licenseviewer/license.xsl"?>
<signedlicense id="[sitecore license id]"> 
...
  <Signature>...</Signature>
...
</signedlicense>
```

#### Response

Status code 200 (OK) is returned for a successful response with the following JSON document in the body:

```json
{
  "Key": "X-ScS-Nexus-Auth",
  "Value": "[sitecore nexus key]"
}
```

---

#### 2. Sitecore Deployment ID

To get a list of all provisioned xDB Sets, call the [List xDB Sets](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/81/xdb_cloud/customizing/rest_api_reference_for_the_xdb_cloud_service#_List_xDB_sets) REST API.

#### Request

```
GET https://gateway-xdb-scs.cloud.sitecore.net/api/xdb/[sitecore license id]
X-ScS-Nexus-Auth: [sitecore nexus key]
```

#### Request Headers

The `X-ScS-Nexus-Auth` is used to authenticate the request to Sitecore xDB Cloud service. It is a string value, unique to your Sitecore License ID.

#### Request Body

None.

#### Response

Status code 200 (OK) is returned for a successful response with the following JSON document in the body:

```json
[
  {
    "DeploymentId": "My-xDB-Cloud-Prod"
  },
  {
    "DeploymentId": "My-xDB-Cloud-NonProd"
  }
]
```

---

#### 3. Sitecore xDB Set Endpoints

To get a list of all endpoints of the specified xDB Set, call the following REST API, which is undocumented.

> This REST API is exactly the same thing that Sitecore xDB Cloud Client
>   calls for xDB Cloud 1.0 if you examine the `Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb`
>   assembly using such tool as [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

#### Request

```
GET https://discovery-xdb-cloud.sitecore.net/xdb/set/[sitecore license id]?DeploymentId=[xdb cloud deployment id]
X-ScS-Nexus-Auth: [sitecore nexus key]
```

#### Request Headers

The `X-ScS-Nexus-Auth` is used to authenticate the request to Sitecore xDB Cloud service. It is a string value, unique to your Sitecore License ID.

#### Request Body

None.

#### Response

Status code 200 (OK) is returned for a successful response with the following JSON document in the body:

```json
{
  "LicenseId": "[sitecore license id]",
  "DeploymentId": "[sitecore xdb cloud deployment id]",
  "XdbConnectionStrings": {
    "analytics": "mongodb://[user-name]:[password]@[host1]:[port1],[host2]:[port2]/[guid]-Analytics?ssl=true;replicaSet=[hostX];connectTimeout=1m;maxIdleTime=1m;socketTimeout=1m",
    "tracking.live": "mongodb://[user-name]:[password]@[host1]:[port1],[host2]:[port2]/[guid]-TrackingLive?ssl=true;replicaSet=[hostX];connectTimeout=1m;maxIdleTime=1m;socketTimeout=1m",
    "tracking.history": "mongodb://[user-name]:[password]@[host1]:[port1],[host2]:[port2]/[guid]-TrackingHistory?ssl=true;replicaSet=[hostX];connectTimeout=1m;maxIdleTime=1m;socketTimeout=1m",
    "tracking.contact": "mongodb://[user-name]:[password]@[host1]:[port1],[host2]:[port2]/[guid]-TrackingContact?ssl=true;replicaSet=[hostX];connectTimeout=1m;maxIdleTime=1m;socketTimeout=1m"
  },
  "ReportingServiceUri": "https://Reporting-[deployment type]-[guid]-[location]-Xdb-Sc.cloudapp.net",
  "DeploymentType": "[Prod | NonProd]",
  "SitecoreVersion": "[sitecore experience platform version]",
  "Location": "[West US | North Europe | Japan East | Australia Southeast]",
  "Indexes": {
    "sitecore-analytics-cloud-index": {
      "Name": "[guid]-analyticsindex",
      "BaseUrl": "https://[search service name].search.windows.net/indexes",
      "QueryKey": "[query key]",
      "ApiVersion": "2015-02-28"
    }
  },
  "XdbCloudVersion": "[1.0 | 2.0]",
  "ReportingServiceCertificate": "[certificate thumbprint]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [Get Connection Strings](https://doc.sitecore.net/xdb_cloud/working_with_xdb_cloud/customizing/rest_api_reference_for_the_xdb_cloud_service#_Get_connection_strings) REST API available for xDB Cloud `2.0`, which you can use on step #3.